# Use text clipping with absolute position

Tags: css

I'm trying to use `background-clip: text;` with `position: absolute;`. But I can't find information about it in even W3C spec. The structure looks like this:

```
 <div> <!-- The element with text-clipped background -->
    <span>Text</span> <!-- position: absolute; -->
 </div>
```

But the text is gone (because I have to use transparent color to use clipping) when I render this in Firefox or Chrome.

Is it possible to do this?

Comment: before the spec better start with *easy* site like the mozilla documentation https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-clip and at the end you will see the spec reference

Comment: @temani-afif There is no information about this too.